# Magento - Which .htaccess/php.ini file affects Import?

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I need to change max_execution_time to hopefully resolve some issues I'm having with Magento 1.5.1.0's Import function. After running `find` in my Magento root directory, I noticed there are a bunch of locations for .htaccess. Which one do I need to edit to fix the Import issue?

NOTE: This is the line in my .htaccess file that I hope is overriding my php.ini settings:

`php_value max_execution_time 18000`

Here is a list:

```
/home/domain/public_html/errors/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/errors/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/var/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/pkginfo/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/includes/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/app/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/lib/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/media/downloadable/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/media/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/downloader/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/magerepair/downloader/template/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/var/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/var/backups/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/pkginfo/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/includes/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/app/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/lib/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/media/downloadable/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/media/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/downloader/.htaccess
/home/domain/public_html/downloader/template/.htaccess
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an htaccess issue? I would think this would be a php.ini issue...

Comment: It is, but my .htaccess file has a `max_execution_time` override in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that I needed to change was located at `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`. This change affected all domains on my server (in my case, only one). It can also be done through Web Host Management by going to PHP Configuration Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Make your change in `/home/domain/public_html/.htaccess` and the setting will be inherited by all others.

Magento has a *front controller* architecture which means everything works through the same `index.php` file. Whatever affects that must affect the whole application too.

Comment: Would my cPanel reflect the PHP config override given in my .htaccess? I've made the changes to `/home/domain/public_html/.htaccess` but cPanel is still reporting that max_execution_time is 30, while .htaccess has this line in it: `php_value max_execution_time 18000`

Comment: cPanel probably won't reflect localised changes. The best way is to create a PHP file in your webspace with just this content `<?php phpinfo();` and then access that file from a browser. It will list all settings both globally and locally.

Comment: It's saying that it's 30 both globally and locally. It seems like the .htaccess modification is not working. I had even placed a modified `php.ini` at `/home/php.ini`. I'm lost as to what to do.

Comment: Sometimes changes to `php.ini` aren't picked up until Apache is restarted. That's something your host could help with - if you're contacting them you might as well ask they increase the execution time and memory limit too.

Comment: I had to fix it through WHM. Tech support tells me that the file that it modifies is at `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

Not all servers are configured to read the .htaccess for php values. Check with your webhost for details, but as Darren stated a php.ini would be the more logical choice to make this php configuration change.

Comment: I have my own dedicated server with root access, so I imagine I can configure it that way if needed. Where can I check to see if the .htaccess override is actually doing anything?

Comment: You could add "AllowOverride All" to your virtualhost configuration.